# How to select specific services of Docker Compose when using spring-boot-docker-compose in Gradle or Maven?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

The latest Spring Boot 3.1 provides the artifact *spring-boot-docker-compose* to start services from `docker-compose.yaml`. Is it possible to select some specific services instead of starting all services? If so can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot will simply run `docker compose up` with the compose file that it found. There is no way for it to directly select individual services to start.

You can create [profiles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) in the compose file, assign services to profiles, and instruct Spring Boot to [pass a profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.docker-compose.profiles) with `docker compose --profile x up`.